# running Hadoop, 4-node cluster. I want to install Impala on the HDFS cluster without the Cloudera Manager

Tags: hive, cloudera, hadoop2, impala

I have an already up and running Hadoop, 4-node cluster. I want to install Impala on the HDFS cluster without the Cloudera Manager.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the link to "Installing Impala without Cloudera Manager":

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/impala_noncm_installation.html

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can install impala

ways of installing :

[click here to install impala on linux machine](https://impala.apache.org/downloads.html)

[Click here to install impala with CM](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/cdh/5-1-x/Impala/Installing-and-Using-Impala/ciiu_cm_installation.html)

[Click here to install impala with Cloudera Quick Start VM](https://www.cloudera.com/downloads/quickstart_vms/5-12.html)

Comment: Impala is Apache open-sourced.  While primarily developed by Cloudera there is no restrictions from using it.  Anyone can go to https://impala.apache.org/downloads.html and download it and use it.

Comment: @tk421 thanks for your help and information which improved my knowledge on impala